# JavaScript Error TypeError: this.$store.state.user.roles.indexOf is not a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, indexof

i need some help. I am receiving this error on my website

```
TypeError: this.$store.state.user.roles.indexOf is not a function
```

I dont really have too much knowledge about JS, but here its the part of my code what contains that var.

```
-1===e.indexOf("dashboard")&&"/submit-property"!==e?-1!==this.$store.state.user.roles.indexOf("buyer")?this.$router.push("/dashboard/favorite"):this.$router.push("/dashboard/properties"):-1!==this.$store.state.user.roles.indexOf("buyer")&&"/submit-property"===e&&this.$router.push("/dashboard/favorite"))
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you show the data ?? What is the type of roles?

Comment: The roles are for Buyer, Admin and agent on a Real Estate Website

Comment: Sorry I want to know the datatype of the roles variable, since indexOf is an array method .

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi You refer to the data that the array gives to that role? Im really new on this, i can show you the complete script